# htaccess - returning 404 errors on xml files?

Tags: xml, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have an installation of WordPress that has a directory containing a number of XML files.  Up until this morning - those files were all accessible via the browser (I could browse directly to them).  But now - trying to call them directly from the browser returns a 404 error.

I'm baffled, because nothing should have changed.  I'm assuming it's an .htaccess issue most likely?

Here's my htaccess:

```
 <Files xmlrpc.php>
 <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
 allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx
 </IfModule>
 </Files>
 # END GOTMLS Patch to Block XMLRPC Access
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

(note - obscured relevant IP addresses)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If 404 error display then htaccess file is wrong.
just change htaccess code from your to my code.

if your files are in folder like www.xyz.com/foldername/
therefor use following code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /foldername/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

if your files is directly on server like www.xyz.com
therefor use following code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

this code for main htaccess file which is in main directory where wp-config file is available and another htaccess is in wp-content folder.
Make another .htaccess file in wp-cotent folder and write following code.

```
#<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
#  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
#    Order allow,deny
#    Deny from all
#  </IfModule>
#  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
#    Require all denied
#  </IfModule>
#</FilesMatch>
```

after this check your wp-admin and it will not display 404 error.